Show to what site the reputation belongs when hovering over the reputation counter on the top bar
I recently had a sinking feeling in my gut: my reputation had dropped by 1/3! Serves me right for posting crappy questions.
But wait, it turns out that number is referring to
each individual Stack Exchange site, not some grand total. I was comparing site A and site B.
Well, at least the mouseover could mention that. All the user sees when they place their pointer over the number is "your reputation: 448".
It could say "your reputation on the XYZ Stack Exchange: 448".


Nobody expects the reputation number to reflect anything but the reputation at that site.

I don't understand. It seems self-explanatory that the reputation displayed on that top banner is for site specific actions.

As you can see in the image, it is possible for site A to even look the same as site B, so don't blame me for using these sites for 10 years before finally figuring out that it is not all one grand total!

"it is possible for site A to even look the same as site B" What do you mean? That images clearly shows "Stack Exchange" not "Stack Overflow", and there's not second image to compare that to to denote a different site appearing to look like another. Each site clearly denotes its name in the upper left corner, and many have their own themes as well (some significantly different), so you can easily tell which site you are on.

Looking at my image, you cannot tell if I am on
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/ vs. https://gis.stackexchange.com/ just from the logos, etc. Especially after I typed "bla" into the search bar. Anyway, at least I know the difference between stack exchange and stock exchange. That some are called overflow and some are called exchange... well that is overflow to my "limited edition" brain. Sorry.

I'm sympathetic that a new user may not realize that reputation is site-specific and more detailed hovertext could solve that, but also feels like a slippery slope. Many many things are site-specific - questions, tags, badges, metas, review queues, etc. - we don't need repeated assurances that you're on the XYZ site and things are XYZ specific (beyond normal page branding). It seems like a user would form a natural realization that certain things are site-specific as one uses the network.

"Looking at my image" I disagree to an extent. Sure, they both have the same banner (the only part you have captured), but that's about the end of the similarities. Both, at the top of the page, state what community they are, and the 2 sites have different themes, including different colours, background and font face.

"10 years before finally figuring out" -- HUH? Your profile says you're  member of 50 different sites, that means 49 explicit clicks on "Join this Community" each followed by a +100 association bonus popping up. You don't have anywhere close to 4.9k rep on any site, wouldn't that tip you off to begin with?

All I know is I read that each (down)vote = 10 reputations and I posted something that got 15 downvotes, and yesterday looking at site A I had 500 reputations, and today looking at site B I had 350, so I freaked out. It turned out that all I needed to do was check site A again and I would have seen that my 500 was still there safe and sound. Also the bad post was on site C, so didn't affect site A or B in the first place. You see I was never point-conscious until recently, so assumed that they were all one big central account. Just like logging in has been made so easy.

As far as the difference between Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, all I know is today in the upper left the logo says Stack Exchange, but in the lower left I see "TEAMS... work with Stack Overflow". So never mind.

"All I know is I read that each (down)vote = 10 reputations" This is incorrect; receiving an upvote is 10 reputation, receiving a downvote is -2 reputation, and casting a downvote on an answer is -1 reputation.

OK, I now see all that in https://stackoverflowteams.help/en/articles/8775594-reputation-and-voting . Odd, it doesn't mention that downvotes are sometimes not always cost-free to the voter!

If you're more used to other sites that are sub-sites under a main one, I'd say/feel that it is less than obvious, especially on the foo.stackexchange.com sites where rep is from. I think this proposal makes sense

I think it is clear that reputation (or badges) is site-specific, for all users. For new users,
they can discover that easily by just clicking each of the sites they joined.
I don't understand: if you don’t know which site are you landing on, you can see the logos of the site. As an example, this is the logo for Stack Overflow and you can know which site are you on.



I think the logos are totally different for each site.
In conclusion, I don’t see the benefit of implementing this feature. It maybe makes the sites more complicated.

"I think the logos are totally different for each sites." They are not; only a small number of Stack Exchange sites have logos in the top bar.

-1. The condescension is unkind and unhelpful, and the actual content here is based on multiple incorrect presumptions about SE network UI, which do nothing to help here at all, and just exemplify exactly the issue that needs fixing.

Our eyes move to the right of the reputation etc. numbers links.  Our eyes see four icons: Inbox, Trophy, Question Mark, and Balloon. Each one of them refers to entire network items. Therefore it is only natural that we thought the reputation numbers link also did the same.
